# How to implement idle time out function using java script for sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to implement idle time out using java script function .It should support in sencha touch .Can anybody tell how to implement it.

HI 
In my application after user logged in from any screen e.g home screen If user in  home screen application come to background.user is not using application more than 10 mins.I should navigate to login screen

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your problem?

Comment: @SagarKhatri I dont have idea to implement it

Comment: But what exactly you want to implement? Can you describe you requirements atleast?

Comment: @SagarKhatri i have updated it